# SQL Server 2008 R2 installation error

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2008-r2

I am struggling since yesterday regarding the error, first my SSMS expired for some reason & I was not able to get it working. I was not able to unistall all the software related to SQL Server & it shared components, I was removing it successfully & I was getting the same error after reinstalling SQL Server 2008 R2 Express & SSMS : `your trial version has expired`.

At last I messed up everything by forcing SQL Server & its component when I removed it with CCleaner as suggested in one of the article.

An now I am not able to install any version of SQL Server whether it be SQL Server 2008, SQL SErver 2008 Express or SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition I get following message for all the version as show here:

[image]

I am not sure what to do either I reinstall windows 7 or try to search further for solution which I would prefer as I had several software installed on my system & it will take me day or so to install all software.

I would appreciate help regarding this

> Log error reporter under file folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log`
>
> Summary.txt
>
> Overall summary:
>   Final result:
>   SQL Server installation failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the
>   problem, uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.
>   Exit code (Decimal):           -2068643839
>   Exit facility code:            1203
>   Exit error code:               1
>   Exit message:                  Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.MsiExtension.PackageInstallProperty.set_FailedPatchedFeatureList(System.Collections.Generic.List`1)'.
>   Start time:                    2012-11-18 16:32:54
>   End time:                      2012-11-18 16:34:07
>   Requested action:              Install
>   Log with failure:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20121118_163146\Detail.txt
>   Exception help link:           http%3a%2f%2fgo.microsoft.com%2ffwlink%3fLinkId%3d20476%26ProdName%3dMicrosoft%2bSQL%2bServer%26EvtSrc%3dsetup.rll%26EvtID%3d50000%26ProdVer%3d10.0.1600.22%26EvtType%3d0x6539C9E6%400x375DE77D
>
> Machine Properties:
>   Machine name:                  WEBD
>   Machine processor count:       4
>   OS version:                    Windows Vista
>   OS service pack:               Service Pack 1
>   OS region:                     United Kingdom
>   OS language:                   English (United States)
>   OS architecture:               x86
>   Process architecture:          32 Bit
>   OS clustered:                  No
>
> Product features discovered:
>   Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition 
>   Version         Clustered
>
> Package properties:
>   Description:                   SQL Server Database Services 2008
>   SQLProductFamilyCode:          {628F8F38-600E-493D-9946-F4178F20A8A9}
>   ProductName:                   SQL2008
>   Type:                          RTM
>   Version:                       10
>   SPLevel:                       0
>   Installation location:         c:\1ecd7ad03bd0c2d4ee57a72099f430\x86\setup\
>   Installation edition:          EXPRESS
>
> User Input Settings:
>   ACTION:                        Install
>   ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      False
>   AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 
>   AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
>   AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
>   ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
>   ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
>   ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
>   ASDATADIR:                     Data
>   ASDOMAINGROUP:                 
>   ASLOGDIR:                      Log
>   ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
>   ASSVCACCOUNT:                  
>   ASSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
>   ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
>   ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            
>   ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
>   BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
>   CONFIGURATIONFILE:
>         CUSOURCE:
>         ENABLERANU:                    False
>         ERRORREPORTING:                False
>         FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE,REPLICATION,SNAC_SDK
>         FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
>         FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           
>         FTSVCACCOUNT:                  
>         FTSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
>         HELP:                          False
>         INDICATEPROGRESS:              False
>         INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
>         INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
>         INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             
>         INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
>         INSTANCEID:                    
>         INSTANCENAME:                  
>         ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
>         ISSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
>         ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
>         NPENABLED:                     0
>         PCUSOURCE:
>         PID:                           *****
>         QUIET:                         False
>         QUIETSIMPLE:                   False
>         RSINSTALLMODE:                 FilesOnlyMode
>         RSSVCACCOUNT:                  
>         RSSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
>         RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
>         SAPWD:                         *****
>         SECURITYMODE:                  
>         SQLBACKUPDIR:                  
>         SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
>         SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 
>         SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****
>         SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
>         SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           
>         SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  
>         SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               
>         SQLUSERDBDIR:                  
>         SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               
>         SQMREPORTING:                  False
>         TCPENABLED:                    0
>         X86:                           False
>
> Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20121118_163146\ConfigurationFile.ini
>
> Detailed results:
>   Feature:                       Database Engine Services
>   Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
>   MSI status:                    Passed
>   Configuration status:          Passed
>
> ```
>   Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
>   Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
>   MSI status:                    Passed
>   Configuration status:          Passed
>
>   Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
>   Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
>   MSI status:                    Passed
>   Configuration status:          Passed
>
> Rules with failures:
>
> Global rules:
>
> Scenario specific rules:
>
> Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup
> ```
>
> Bootstrap\Log\20121118_163146\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
>
> ```
> Exception summary:
> The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
> Inner exceptions are being indented
>
> Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionExecutionException
>     Message: 
>         Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.MsiExtension.PackageInstallProperty.set_FailedPatchedFeatureList(System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.String>)'.
>     Data: 
>       DisableWatson = true
>     Stack: 
>
>         Server stack trace:
>         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.ExecuteWorkflowAction.HandleActionException(Exception
> ```
>
> e, TextWriter logging)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionEngine.NotifyOnUnhandledException(Exception
>   e)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionEngine.RunActionQueue()
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.Workflow.RunWorkflow(HandleInternalException
>   exceptionHandler)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.ExecuteWorkflowAction.ExecuteAction(String
>   actionId)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.NestedWorkflow.ExecuteWorkflow(ServiceContainer
>   context, String sequencesRootPath, ActionKey sequenceId)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.NestedWorkflow.ExecuteWorkflow(ServiceContainer
>   context, String sequenceId)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.InstallWizardFramework.InstallWizardPageHost.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0()
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.WizardFramework.BlockingWorker.ThreadCallBack(MethodInvoker
>   method)
>               at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean
>   fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
>               at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.PrivateProcessMessage(RuntimeMethodHandle
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean
>   fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
>               at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>
> ```
>         Exception rethrown at [0]:
>         at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message
> ```
>
> reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
>               at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed,
>   MessageData& msgData)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.WizardFramework.BlockingWorker.WorkerCallback.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.WizardFramework.BlockingWorker.PerformWork(MethodInvoker
>   method)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.InstallWizardFramework.InstallWizardPageHost.ExecuteAction(String
>   actionName)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.InstallWizardFramework.InstallWizardPageHost.PageLeft(PageChangeReason
>   reason)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.WizardFramework.UIHost.set_SelectedPageIndex(Int32
>   value)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.WizardFramework.UIHost.GoNext()
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.WizardFramework.NavigationButtons.nextButton_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>               at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>               at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>               at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>               at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>               at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>               at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>               at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>               at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>               at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>               at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>           Inner exception type: System.MissingMethodException
>               Message: 
>                       Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.MsiExtension.PackageInstallProperty.set_FailedPatchedFeatureList(System.Collections.Generic.List`1)'.
>               Stack: 
>                       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.SetFeatureConfigStateAction.ExecuteAction(String
>   actionId)
>                       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String
>   actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
>                       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.InvokeAction(WorkflowObject
>   metabase, TextWriter statusStream)
>                       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.PendingActions.InvokeActions(WorkflowObject
>   metaDb, TextWriter loggingStream)

Related question which i had asked yesterday https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/sql-server-2008-r2-management-studio-evaluation-period-has-expired/28878#28878

**Configuration**: Window 7 32 bit with 4GB RAM

Comment: I had a similar issue once and I was able to get around it by simply running the Setup.exe program as Administrator (Right-Click on it in Windows explorer and select Run as Administrator). I know it sounds silly because you're most likely already logged on to the machine with an admin account, but Windows still requires this for some programs.

Comment: Just have a try with SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2012 R2, SQL Server 2014. Maybe you're lucky.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that i know is that even when you install any type of program it creates registry entries. Sometimes keys are kept there or in a log file. Uninstalling the program will do you no good if you were running a trial version of SQL-Server. you will have to delete the directories out of ProgramFiles on your local hdd and also out of the registry. This has been a workaround for me for all trial version programs that i have ever installed. when deleting from the registry be careful that you don't delete something that you are not suppose too. Otherwise a format should be in order. Running something as administrator as far as I know does not solve this problem. Unless proof can be provided.

Also on a side note. before uninstalling SQL-Server you must stop the instances for it to delete all components related to SQL